# Click-through with hover effect in CSS

Tags: css, hover, mousehover, pointer-events, click-through

I'm trying to make a button without a link, as the background is already linked. Therefore you should be able to cick through it. I know about *pointer-events:none* but when using this, the div's *:hover* won't work anymore.

Is there any way to achieve this?

My HTML is:

```
<div class="button">
<span>Click here</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button { pointer-events: none; }
.button:hover { ... }
```

The "button" class should have an :hover effect + click through. This setup won't show the :hover effect.

Comment: Is the background, which is linked, only behind the button or does it span 100% width of the page?

Comment: Not 100% of the page, but bigger than the button

Comment: Can you also include the HTML and CSS of how you're adding the background?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not able to do that. I'm using Magento and I'm not completely sure where it is pulled from.

Comment: Same dilemma for me! Need pointer-events:none to detect the input element beneath but the hover effect of the layer disappear. A layer with opacity:0 has a remove-button at right end that should be visible on hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code I would suggest one of two routes:

1) Just link both. No bigs.

2) Link your background via javascript. If the button is a child element, the click event will bubble to your linked background.

Comment: 1) Rather a problem in this case, as it should be easy editable for everyone 2) Thanks, I will try that, but would have prefered a CSS only solution.

Comment: To clarify - there is no CSS only solution that meets your criteria. These are the options :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `.button:hover { ... }` by:

```
.background:hover .button { ... }
```

Set the class on your linked background:

```
<a class="background" href="...">
    <button class="button">...</button>
</a>
```

The hovering area size becomes the same as the buttons click area.
With `.background{display:block}` you can make a dummy button with bigger hovering area (that also is the click area). That is good for old people trying hit small buttons on small mobile displays. A bigger hovering area is also useful on desktops for preloading, optimize latency, analytic heat mapping, highlight hidden buttons, and other trix.

**Alternative**

```
.background:hover {
    /* hovering effects */
}

.background:hover ~ button {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    pointer-events:none; /* click through */
}
```

Use [the adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) `'+'` or [the general sibbling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) `'~'`. Instead of `href` you can have `onclick`:

```
<div class="background" onclick="..."></div>
<button>...</button>
```

Comment: The only drawback to this is that the :hover effect will trigger when you mouse over the background, which, as the OP stated, is somewhat larger than the button.  Also makes the specificity higher if you're one that cares about such things.

Comment: Add <a class="background" href="..."><div class="button">...</div></a> with same link as beneath but a hovering area size set to be same as the button.

Comment: Fair enough.  You might want to edit that into your answer for the sake of completeness.